# Azure Mobile Services Android Offline Example - "createdAt","updatedAt" columns empty

Tags: android, sqlite, azure

i have added in the ToDoItem table of the local DB of the mobile device the columns "createdAt" and "updatedAt", because they also exist in the Azure Database ToDoItem table. Those columns are never updated in the localstorage table although i refresh the list (the other table columns are updated normally).
Why could this happen?
The example i followed is here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/07/offline-support-in-azure-mobile-services-android-sdk/

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Without having seen any of your code I assume you haven't decorated the CreatedAt and UpdatedAt properties with the corresponding annotations. Make sure your properties look like this and it should work:

```
    [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CreatedAt]
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.UpdatedAt]
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
```

Ps. you don't have to add these columns of your aren't using them.

Comment: He is asking you for android and you are giving him code for .NET (C#)

Comment: Ah I see, I ran into the same issue (in .NET) and came across this post. I was able to solve it this way and posted my solution. I overlooked the Android tag but I hope it may point you in the right direction. I guess it is up to you to find out if there is a similar annotation for Android. Good luck.