# Why are createdAt, deleted and updatedAt columns null in MobileServiceSQLiteStore database?

Tags: .net, sqlite, azure, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I am using the Azure Mobile App service to synchronise data between a UWP application and Azure. I am using the MobileServiceSQLiteStore class to set up a local Sqlite store to hold data locally, and the MobileServiceClient class to sync local changes to Azure, all as per the quick start on Azure.

My problem is that when I use the InsertAsync method to store data to the local SqlLite store, the createdAt, updatedAt and deleted columns in the store are not being populated. All other columns are being populated as expected. These are the standard columns that the framework expects on my model and I have annotated them as recommended (eg. [CreatedAt])

The linked question highlights the same problem, but for android, and the suggested answer I am already doing, so did not help: [Azure Mobile Services Android Offline Example - "createdAt","updatedAt" columns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884770/azure-mobile-services-android-offline-example-createdat-updatedat-columns)

Is anyone able to help?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;

namespace Test
{
    public class SyncManagerTest
    {
        public SyncManagerTest()
        {
            var client = new MobileServiceClient(@"https://remote.azurewebsites.net");

            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("test.db");

            store.DefineTable<Model>();

            client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

            var table = client.GetSyncTable<Model>();

            table.InsertAsync(new Model
            {
                Name = "Test",
                AnotherDate = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                AnotherBool = true
            });
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        [CreatedAt]
        public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        [Deleted]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; } = false;

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset AnotherDate { get; set; }
        public bool AnotherBool { get; set; }
        [UpdatedAt]
        public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }
}
```

Here is the resulting record in the database:

[image: Database record screenshot]

**Update**
After using dotPeek to have a look at the code for InsertAsync I found:

```
JObject jobject = await this.<>n__1(MobileServiceSyncTable.RemoveSystemPropertiesKeepVersion(serializer.Serialize((object) instance) as JObject));
```

The method RemoveSystemPropertiesKeepVersion is removing the createdAt, updatedAt and deleted properties from the JObject that is written to the database. Does anyone know why this is being done? I can't see anywhere in the database where date information is kept for operations on the database, how does the sync work? Even the __operations metadata table created by the framework in the Sqlite database doesn't contain a date for each operation.

Answer (score 1):

The createdAt and updatedAt fields are updated by the database, not by you.  If you push the record to the server, they will be populated for you.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but how does the framework know when the record was created? What if the next push is one week after the record was created locally and there have been many app restarts in between. I don't see where this date information is stored? Or are you saying that createdAt and updatedAt are set to the push date? And what about the deleted column? How does the framework know if the record has been deleted or not?

Comment: createdAt and updatedAt are stored and updated at the server-side database.  deleted is false by default (i.e. undeleted), but handled as any other field.